# jq transform JSON structure by finding output values in input nested array

Tags: json, transform, jq

First of all, I’m sorry about the title. Even though English isn’t my first language, I wouldn’t even know how to call what I’m trying to accomplish in my mother tongue.

What I’m trying to do is take an input (automatically generated by downloading a page with `curl`, then converted from HTML to JSON in a very crude way using `pup`) and convert it into something that would be easier to work with later on. The input looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "children": [
   {
    "class": "label label-info",
    "tag": "span",
    "text": "Lesson"
   },
   {
    "tag": "h2",
    "text": "Is That So?"
   },
   {
    "tag": "p",
    "text": "Learn how to provide shortened answers with そうです and stay in the conversation with そうですか."
   },
   {
    "class": "btn btn-primary",
    "href": "https://www.nihongomaster.com/japanese/lessons/view/62/is-that-so",
    "tag": "a",
    "text": "Read Lesson"
   }
  ],
  "class": "row col-sm-12",
  "tag": "div"
 },
 {
  "children": [
   {
    "class": "label label-warning",
    "tag": "span",
    "text": "Drills"
   },
   {
    "tag": "h2",
    "text": "Yes, That Is So."
   },
   {
    "tag": "p",
    "text": "Practice the phrases and vocab from the lesson, Is That So?"
   }
  ],
  "class": "row col-sm-12",
  "tag": "div"
 }
]
```

And my desired output would pull various values from each object’s `children` array into something like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Is That So?", // <-- in other words, find "tag" == "h2" and output "text" value
    "perex": "Learn how to provide shortened answers with そうです and stay in the conversation with そうですか.", // "tag" == "p", "text" value
    "type": "lesson", // "tag" == "span", "text" value (lowercased if possible? Not needed though)
    "link": "https://www.nihongomaster.com/japanese/lessons/view/62/is-that-so" // "tag" == "a", "href" value
  },
  {
    "title": "Yes, That Is So."
    "perex": "Practice the phrases and vocab from the lesson, Is That So?",
    "type": "drills",
    "link": null // Can be missing!
  }
]
```

I tried various experiments with the `select` function but got nowhere near any usable result, so I’m not sure if my attempts are even worth sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution to the original problem:

```
[
  .[]
  | .children
  | { title: [.[] | select(.tag == "h2") | .text][0],
      perex: [.[] | select(.tag == "p") | .text][0],
      type:  [.[] | select(.tag == "span") | .text | ascii_downcase][0],
      link:  [.[] | select(.tag == "a") | .href][0] }
]
```

The key point here is the use of the idiom `[...][0]` to handle all possibilities with respect to the number of items in `...` (including 0).

Comment: Nice, thank you so much! I like the second line, it nicely eliminates the need to repeat `.children[]` for each key – I did not think of traversing like that. I’ll adjust your answer to collect the output into an array and mark it as a solution ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

In the process of writing the above question, I somewhat randomly stumbled upon the correct solution. Rather than keeping the knowledge for myself, I thought I’d share the answer here as well. Please feel free to delete this entire question & answer if that’s not aligned to the site rules (I’m sorry if that’s the case).

`select` really is the key, but I was not using it in the correct way at the time of writing the question. Here is the full `jq` command to accomplish my needs, showcasing all of the above requirements:

- how to select the nested values based on searching through the `children` array;
- how to lowercase the `type` value;
- how to deal with sometimes missing `link` values;
- (and I did not realize at that time, but sometimes I want to alter the form of the `link`, so I added that as well).

```
def format(link): if link | tostring | startswith("/") then "https://www.nihongomaster.com" + link else link end;

[.[] | { title: .children[] | select(.tag == "h2").text, type: .children[] | select(.tag == "span").text | ascii_downcase, perex: .children[] | select(.tag == "p").text, link: format(((.children[] | select(.tag == "a").href) // null)) }]
```

There really is nothing better than rubber-duck debugging.